# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Movie'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Movie'
please someone help me solve this problem thaks

I am getting error when trying to run in flutter (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

[error line number 96](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g5MO.png)

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:realstate/home%20page/addingpage.dart';
import 'package:realstate/home%20page/inkwall.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import '../account page/account page.dart';
import '../my stats.dart';
import '../notifcatoin.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  CollectionReference Detabase =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Detabase');
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Detabase').snapshots();
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData() {
    return Detabase.snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            "Home",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 32),
          ),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_business_sharp,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 26,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Addingpage()));
            },
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AccountPage()));
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.account_circle,
              ),
              color: Colors.black,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              focusColor: Colors.transparent,
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _usersStream,
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Something went wrong');
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text("Loading");
              }

              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                  (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic>? data =
                        document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                    return MovieItem(data[Index] ?? "");
                  },
                ).toList(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

plEASE someone solve this problem it toke me 2 weeks

I am getting error when trying to run in flutter (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Comment: seems like your issue is with the Movie.dart file, you need to share that and provide some context of what you are trying to achieve so people can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you provided 2 diffrent errors

so yea and the coode looks diffrent at the snippet

Ok so at

```
return MovieItem(data[Index] ?? "");
```

you are returning data[index] but if it is null you are returning `""`

so `MovieItem("")`

you should do it

```
return MovieItem(data[Index] ?? null);
```

Comment: hi this what i reached

Answer (score 0):

And what do you get in `snapshot.data` from Firebase? Can you display that data?

Comment: i cant understand what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

try add **where** before map
and **!** instead of **??""**

like this :

```
      return ListView(
        children: snapshot.data!.docs.where((e)=>e!=null).map(
          (DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic>? data =
                document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

            return MovieItem(data[Index]!);
          },
        ).toList(),
```

because some of docs items is is null and you cannot replace it with String